# Is there a term for this logical property?

Tags: logic, formal-systems

Suppose I am working in a standard formal theory such as ZFC or NBG.

Consider this statement:

"For all well-formed formulas *s*, ((there exists a proof *p* s.t. *p* is a valid proof of *s*) --> *s*)"

I'm fairly familiar with some of the basic facts of logic, e.g., Tarski's undefinability theorem, Godel's theorems, and the difference between "consistency" and "soundness."

Nonetheless, I have two questions:

1)  Is this a theorem of ZFC/NBG?  (What would a proof look like?)

2)  Is there a term for this property of formal theories?  E.g., "soundness," "consistency," and "completeness" are terms for other different properties.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this cannot even be stated in the language of ZFC or NBG - you cannot express truth of arbitrary sentence in the language.

Comment: I think you are right.  Technically, I would have to say, "For all integers *n* in N, ... --> n is the Godel number of a true sentence."  Thanks.

Comment: That still won't work - one can't express "n is the Godel number of a true sentence".

Comment: I understand...I was just explaining why it would not work.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, that's correct. However, you can still ask about systems which prove, for every sentence, "s is provable -> s".

Comment: Actually, on second thought, I think your initial comment was mistaken...see the answer below.

Comment: The answer below (and Lob's theorem itself) doesn't deal with actual truth of statements, but with provability. To rephrase it in your terms, Lob's theorem gives ""For all well-formed formulas s, (Provable(there exists a proof p s.t. p is a valid proof of s) --> Provable(s))".

Comment: @Wojowu: Löb's theorem does not say that. Read my answer and the link therein. For a sound system, like PA, Löb's theorem implies that a system like ZFC cannot prove $\mathsf{Provable}(\phi) \to \phi$ for any $\phi$ that is not true.

Comment: @RobArthan Ah, I see my mistake. I will have to give this thing a better look later. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Wojowu: For much more details, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1766631/21820).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Löb's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem) says that (in any sufficiently strong system) for any sentence $\phi$, if $\mathsf{Provable}(\phi) \to \phi\;$ is provable then $\phi$ is provable (so that the hypothesis in $\mathsf{Provable}(\phi) \to \phi\;$ was vacuous). A sound system that proves $\mathsf{Provable}(\phi) \to \phi\;$ for any $\phi$ that is not true is inconsistent.