# Are there any statements that are n-undecidable for all n?

Tags: logic, infinity, philosophy, turing-machines, decidability

I understand that in a sufficiently complicated, consistent formal system, not all statements are true, not all statements are decidable, not all statements' decidability is decidable, 3-decidable, ..., $n$-decidable.

Where a statement is $n$-decidable if its $n-1$-decidability is decidable.

[There is no $n$ for which all statements are $n$-decidable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4400625/3157)

But is it also true that there are statements that are $n$-**un**decidable for all $n$?

If so, is there any notion of higher undecidabilities?  $\omega$-undecidable?

If not, what prevents [Hilbert's program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_program)?  I don't see how even a boundless $n$ would prevent it (although I am vaguely thinking of something akin to the diagonalization argument).

Comment: What is "n-undecidable" ?

Comment: A statement is $n$-decidable if its $n-1$-decidability is decidable

Comment: Just to check: a statemement is $0$-decidable if it is decidable; it is $n+1$-decidable if its $n$-decidability is decidable, is that it? In any case, doesn't Rice's theorem imply a positive answer to the title question?